# Get elements between 2 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html:

```
<div class="categories">
    <div class="list-group">
        <a class="root list-group-item" id="427" style="display: block;"><span class="glyphicon indent0 glyphicon-chevron-down"></span><span>Home</span></a>
        <a class="list-group-item first active" id="428" style="display: block;"><span class="glyphicon indent1 glyphicon-chevron-right"></span><span>Images</span></a>
        <a class="list-group-item child" id="431" style="display: none;"><span class="glyphicon indent2"></span><span>Sub category</span></a>
        <a class="list-group-item first" id="429" style="display: block;"><span class="glyphicon indent1 glyphicon-chevron-right"></span><span>Videos</span></a>
        <a class="list-group-item child" id="432" style="display: none;"><span class="glyphicon indent2"></span><span>Another sub</span></a>
        <a class="list-group-item first" id="430" style="display: block;"><span class="glyphicon indent1"></span><span>Documents</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and what I need to do is select all elements between **a.active**.
To explain that a little better; **a.active** has a **span.glyphicon** with the class **indent1**, so I need to select the elements between **indent1** and the next **indent1**

I attempted to use jQuery's **nextAll** function but couldn't get it to work correctly :(

any help would be appreciated,

/r3plica

**Update 1**

Thanks to Arun, here is my script which now works:

```
$(".glyphicon", treeRoot).on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    var $glyph = $(this);
    var $item = $glyph.parent();
    var indent = $item.find(".glyphicon").prop('className').match(/\b(indent\d+)\b/)[1];

    console.log($item[0].outerHTML);
    console.log(indent);

    if (indent != undefined) {
        var $children = $item.nextUntil("a:has(." + indent + ")");

        console.log($children[0].outerHTML);

        if ($glyph.hasClass("glyphicon-chevron-right")) {
            $glyph
                .addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down')
                .removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-right");

            if ($children != null) $children.show();
        } else {
            $glyph
                .addClass('glyphicon-chevron-right')
                .removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down");

            if ($children != null) $children.hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You'd help yourself a lot here if you had a better structure to represent your hierarchy. How about nested `<ul>`s?

Comment: Just to say it: Id's shouldnt start with a number!

Comment: @cbuckly the structure is defined by bootstrap3 listgroup with links. Nothing to do with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('.active').nextUntil('a:has(.indent1)')
```

To dynamically determine the indent value

```
var $active = $('.active');
var indent = $active.find('.glyphicon').prop('className').match(/\b(indent\d+)\b/)[1];

var $nexts = $active.nextUntil('a:has(.' + indent + ')');
console.log($nexts)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eR22m)

Comment: For me the indent code doesn't work. I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined". I was using 
var indent = $.grep($item.attr("class").split(" "), function (v, i) {
            return v.indexOf('indent') === 0;
        }).join();

Comment: jQuery version used.. the fiddle seems to be working

Comment: @r3plica it looks like the `glyphicon` element is not there... are you running the script in a dom ready handler

Comment: Just updating my question so you can see :)

Comment: it's part of a plugin that is activated by calling $(".categories").buildTree(); which then uses ajax to populate and build the tree

Comment: yeah, you were right. It was becuase I was calling $item.find(".glyphicon") but the element $item is the icon :/ the indent is now correct, but I still dont get any children

Answer (score 1):

Try using [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9RpfC/1/)**

```
$('.active:has(.indent1)').nextUntil(':has(.indent1)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with  **nextUntil** (from Jquery)
 
Look at http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

```
$('.active').nextUntil('.indent1');
```